# MYSQL Timezone support

Tags: mysql, timezone

We are having a shared hosting plan and they are saying  that do provide MYSQL Timezone support in a shared hosting plan. I can create timezone related tables in our database and populate them with required data(data from from our local MYSQL Timezone related tables. How to view the code syntax for MySQL "CONVERT_TZ" function?

Thanks
Arun

Comment: Answer already exist in stackoverflow.com [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)

Answer (score 2):

In order to timezone support to be around, the hosting company should have executed this:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql ...
```

The [**mysql_tzinfo_to_sql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) utility should load the time zones. Please make sure the host company has done this. If they can't or won't,

- you could into Amazon EC2, you could have full access to MySQL and can run it yourself
- Find a willing hosting company

BTW Here is the MySQL Documentation for **`CONVERT_TZ`** : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems that the hosting provider is not willing to do that. I have referred this link and asked them. Before purchasing the plan their support team confirmed me about their support for MySQL Timezone. I know the CONVERT_TZ date/time execution syntax. I have asked for something like "SHOW FUNCTION CODE" to view how this CONVERT_TZ function is implemented in MySQL Server and try to adopt and create as a user defined function so that I may execute the function against the Timezone related tables adopted from MySQL and created by me in our local database. Thanks-Arun

Comment: @pranivi - Were you successful in creating a user-defined equivalent to the CONVERT_TZ function which utilises your local timezone-related database tables?